# Best way to understand ratios for variables that differ in size

Tags: data-visualization, python, data-transformation, model-evaluation

I have data on a number of sites, and variables measuring attributes of that site like size, location, data metrics, etc. One variable is a performance metric in the form of a ratio of two site specific attributes. Unfortunately, the ratio defines performance only in relation to the site itself, not in comparison to other sites of different sizes.  So for example, Site A with performance ratio 0.65 and size 10 is different in ‘raw’ terms than Site B with performance ratio 0.65 and size 5, but the performance ratio alone doesn’t see this difference.

What are some good ways to either combine or relate the single performance ratio to the size of the site? Or perhaps there are different ways that I could look at this? I cannot change the performance ratio so hoping some of you guys can offer me a helping hand in how to order these ratios in respect to size.  The end goal is coming up with a priority rating list of sites.

note - the performance ratio is measuring performance using the observed data and simulation data.

Comment: Can you be more specific about these data? Are they schools, rivers, microarrays, ...? Is size integral? Have you considered frequency weighting?

Comment: These are power plants with associated performance ratios. The size variable is the rated AC capacity in MW.

Comment: What is the performance then?

Comment: The performance is a series of calculations (ends in ratio form) that standardizes the actual output vs the modeled output.

Comment: It's very important for advice to know the bounds of these ratios: are they $0 \le $ ratio $\le 1$ or $0 < $ ratio $< 1$ or $0 \le $ ratio or $0 < $ ratio or what?

Comment: @Rivers31334 is this like a model of engine efficiency? So a ratio of 0.65 is a 35% shortage in theoretical energy output? And the suspicion is that bigger power sources may be more or (probably) less efficient than their smaller counterparts?

Comment: @NickCox The ratio is is inclusive of 0, and can be > 1. Meaning if observed output was X and modeled output was X+10, the ratio could be >1.

Comment: @AdamO You are more or less correct.  The components of the final ratio are measures of efficiency for both obs and model. So (obs efficiency / modeled efficiency) to get final performance metric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linear regression model can be modified arithmetically to model, predict, and infer associations for ratio based outcomes. The problem as I understand it is that the ratio outcome is a fraction of an empirical quantity to a theoretical quantity. The model which is written as:

$$ E[N/D | X] = \beta_0 \exp( \beta_1 X)$$

can be modified with a log transform to obtain:

$$ E[\log(N)) | X] = b_0 + b_1 X + \text{offset}(\log(D))$$

Here the $N$ (numerator) is the observed energy output of the system. $D$ (denominator) is the theoretical upper bound, adjusted as a covariate in the linear model with an effect that is constrained to be 1. The other free-parameters are estimated with better precision and generalizability since the theoretical output is controlled for.

Comment: Thanks. I am going work through this and if all goes well, I'll be back to mark as accepted answer.